# Change style (hover) of an element after ajax request

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, hover

when i use this js code :

```
$(".superclass").mouseenter(function() {
$(this).find('p').first().attr('style','background-color:#ff0000');});
$('.superclass').mouseleave(function() {
$(this).find('p').first().attr('style','background-color:#000000');});
```

and i make an ajax request and add result inside output

```
<div id="output"> <div class="superclass"><p>....</p></div></div>
```

the hover effect does not work anymore .

Is it possible to make it work ?

Comment: Hi, you need to bind your event handler with some static elements i.e : `$("#output").on('mouseenter','.superclass',function() {..` same for other as well .

Comment: Perfect, it works now. on act as a super global function ?